# Asterisk integration with custom ERP

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

One of our customers has an Asterisk phone center and want to integrate it with our ERP. The idea is that Asterisk calls an Oracle database procedure when a phone call is transferred to an extension. This Oracle procedure has 2 parameters, incoming phone number and destination extension.

Is it possible to do this with Asterisk API? Where can I find documentation or examples to do it?

I have read official Asterisk API documentation but don't understand how it works and where can I begin to search...

Answer (score 0):

There are no documentation for "just integrate with ERP".

You can use ARI events or AMI events or CEL to make integrations. It will be highly depend of dialplan used

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a dozen ways to do this using the various Asterisk subsystems, such as ARI and AMI, but one of the simplest might be to make a network call embedded in the dialplan.

There are several examples of how this might be done at https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-call-notification/ ; for example, look at the description for YAC on that page, which shows how to make the call using netcat.

That method uses the [System Application](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+17+Application_System).  Do be careful not to pass unfiltered text from e.g. the Caller ID information to the system, as someone might inject malicious code into the Caller ID.